# Lebesgue Domination Convergence and $L^1$ Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm working on a problem in my notes about LDC implying $L^1$ convergence.

We will let $m$ denote Lebesgue measure and $\| \cdot \|_1$ denote $L^1$ norm. Further for $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R^n})$ and each $r>0$ define the function

$$A_{f,r}(x):= \frac{1}{m(B(x,r))}\int_{B(x,r)} f dm$$

LDC says that $A_{f,r}$ converges to $f$ pointwise for a.e. $x$ as $r \rightarrow 0$.

The problem at hand is to show that in fact $A_{f,r}$ converges to $f$ in the $L^1$ norm.

The hint is to prove it in three steps: 1) assuming that $f$ is continuous and compactly supported, 2) show that for $r>0$ , $A_{f,r} \in L^1(\mathbb{R^n})$, and finally 3) prove it for all $L^1$ functions using a density argument.

The hint is straightforward enough but I'm having difficulty on the first step. My thoughts are that since $f$ is continuous and compactly supported, it is uniformly continuous. Then we can bound $|f(y)-f(x)|$ for any fixed $x$ as long as $r$ is sufficiently small. But then I run into the difficulty of double integrals when working out what it actually means for $\|A_{f,r} -f \|_1 \rightarrow 0$. Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose from your question that you have already seen that 
$$
  A_{f,r}(x) - f(x) = \frac{1}{m(B(x,r))} \int_{B(x,r)} (f(y) - f(x)) m(dy)
$$
Now, due to the compact support of $f$, $A_{f,r}$ is compactly supported,
too. So, you have to consider $|A_{f,r}(x) - f(x)|$ on a compact support only.

The uniform continuity yields now that $|f(x) - f(y)| < \varepsilon$ if $r>0$ is small enough, independent of $x$ and $y$, that is only the difference $|x-y|$ matters. The inner integral for the norm is then arbitrary small....

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up figuring it out before I read this, but I got the same result so it's nice to see it verified.

Comment: Glad to see that you found the solution on your own and that I could confirm it.